# Infowindow content updates correctly when pin is clicked, but stays above the same pin regardless of what pin is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

Alright, here we go with a minimal reproducible example (I believe).

So, to start with, I read a csv file with 3 columns: Name, placeID, type.
The types have been manually defined, and a dropdown in the html is populated with unique types.

When a type is chosen, the map should display a pin on the location of each place with a corresponding type as the choice in the dropdown.

Here is code for the searchplacesbytype function:

```
    function searchPlacesByType(map, placeType) {
  const promises = [];
  placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  var request = {
      radius: 1000,
      language: 'no',
      type: 'school',
      business_status: 'OPERATIONAL',
      fields: ['name', 'rating', 'formatted_address', 'formatted_phone_number'],
    };
    for (const placeId of placeIDs) {
      promises.push(
        getPlaceCoordinates(placeId).then(coordinates => {
          return {
            placeId: placeId,
            coordinates1: coordinates
          };
        })
      );
    } 
// Wait for all promises to resolve
    Promise.all(promises)
      .then(coordinatesArray => {
    // Process the coordinates for each place ID
    for (const coordinates of coordinatesArray) {
        //Personal comment: I believe this is where I'm doing something wrong...
        const lat = coordinates.coordinates1.latitude;
        const long = coordinates.coordinates1.longitude;
        request.placeId = coordinates.placeId;
        const coordinatesSend = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
        const distance = calculateDistance(map.getCenter(), coordinatesSend);
        if(typeof distance === 'number'&& !isNaN(distance)) {
          placesService.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              createMarker(place, coordinates.placeId, coordinatesSend);
            } else {
              console.error('Place details request failed:', status);
            }
          });
        } else {
          console.log('The value is not a number');
        }
  }
    })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Errores:', error);
  });

    
  }
```

The createmarker function looks like this:

```
    // Create a marker for a place
function createMarker(place, PlaceID, coordinates) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: coordinates,
        title: place.name,
    });
    
      // Add click event listener to each marker
      marker.addListener('click', () => {
        showPlaceDetails(PlaceID);
      });
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

At last, the shoplacedetails function looks like this:

```
    function showPlaceDetails(placeId) {
    const request = {
      placeId: placeId,
      fields: ['name', 'formatted_address', 'formatted_phone_number', 'types'],
    };
  
    placesService.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
    const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      const name = place.name;
      const address = place.formatted_address;
      const phoneNumber = place.formatted_phone_number;
      const type = place.types[0];
  
      // Customize the info window content
      const content = `
        <h2>${name}</h2>
        <p>Address: ${address}</p>
        <p>Phone Number: ${phoneNumber}</p>
        <p>Type: ${type}</p>
        `;
        infoWindow.setContent(content);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    });
  }
```

What happens now is that the pins are displayed correctly according to the placeIDs read in the csv file, but the infowindow remains above the same pin regardless of what pin i click. Even though the infowindow does not move to the correct pin however, it's content is updated correctly relevant to the pin I click...

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or a working code snippet so that we can check the error itself. Stack overflow have this feature, so you should try it out.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your code here: https://jsbin.com/zopisuzixo/3/edit?html,js,output but I can't see the issue on my end. So my comment above about providing your own code that reproduces the issue still stands.

Comment: Thanks @Yrll ! I'll do so later on today!

Comment: Updated with code now, @Yrll . Is this sufficient, or should I insert the whole js file along with the html file?

Comment: Stack Overflow have this feature where you can put the html/css/js in your question/answer and make your code runnable. Then use this Google Maps SO Test Key: AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk. So yes, please do include the html/css also.

Comment: I can't reproduce the code you provided because the data supplied in the for loop is not included, you can also try putting your code in codesandbox or other snippet sites where you can include other files like your data.

Comment: I solved this based on help on Discord. The solution was to pass along the marker from the createMarker function to the showPlaceDetails function.